# Error with docker using postgres and prisma

Tags: postgresql, docker, backend, prisma

I need help, I don't find the solution anywhere. I launched a docker on Ubuntu, this is my docker configuration for Postgres and my backend:

```
backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - back
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres 
postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15
      #env_file: .env
      #environment:
      #- POSTGRES_DB=transcendance
      #- POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      #- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes :
      - db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - db
```

This is my env file:

```
POSTGRES_DB=transcendance
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myuser
POSTGRES_USER=mypass

DATABASE_URL=postgresql://myuser:mypass@db:5432/transcendance?schema=public
#[TYPE_DB]://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[HOST]:[PORT]/[DB_NAME]

SOCKET_PORT=4242
DB_PORT=5432
BACK_PORT=3000
FRONT_PORT=8080
```

When I use the env file or env variable to set my Postgres variable, I get an error from the backend. But when I use the value all is done without any error, I don't have any special characters in my env file or any other Postgres instance launched in my machine, the port 5432 is not used I don't understand what is the problem.

This is the error :

```
backend     | Environment variables loaded from .env
backend     | Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
backend     | Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "transcendance", schema "public" at "db:5432"
backend     | 
postgres    | 2023-11-28 08:32:26.923 UTC [33] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
postgres    | 2023-11-28 08:32:26.923 UTC [33] DETAIL:  Role "myuser" does not exist.
postgres    |   Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
backend     | Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `db`, the provided database credentials for `myuser` are not valid.
backend     | 
backend     | Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at `db`.
backend exited with code 1
```

What may be possibly my problem here?

I tried many solutions, using a different port, I see inside the container Postgres if the env variable is set, use different syntax to declare my env variable, maybe other but I don't remember.

Comment: I feel your problem may be related to how you ran the PostgreSQL container initially. Can you remove the volume directory "db-volume", set the variables for this container, start everything again and see if-which errors you still have? It may be easier to help after that.

Comment: I tried the error is the same ...

Comment: Can you edit the question with what you have right now?

Comment: sorry for taking so long to answer, Finally i find the problem,I just reversed this values :
'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myuser
POSTGRES_USER=mypass'
thanks for ur helpful